# Regular Expression not matching specific URL with equal sign in anchor part

Tags: java, regex

i am writing program to validate the URL using Regex . but when i test it against this URL (http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/09/17/stax.html#id=_hbc)
Its fail. Can anyone tells me why its fail to match that URL?
here is the Code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class IPURLValidator {
    private Pattern patternHost;
    private Matcher matcher;
    private static final String hostName = "^((https?)://)([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\\.)*([0-9]*\\_[0-9]*\\_" +
        "[a-zA-Z0-9\\_]*)*([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\\-]*[A-Za-z0-9]){2}" +
        "([0-9]*)?(\\/[\\+~%\\/\\.\\w\\-]*)?\\??([\\-\\+=&;%@\\/%\\.\\w]*)" +
        "#?([\\-\\+=&;%@\\/%\\.\\w]*)$";
    public IPURLValidator() {
        patternHost = Pattern.compile(hostName, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    }
    public boolean validateHost(String host) {
        matcher = patternHost.matcher(host);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            String HostName = matcher.group(0);
            System.out.println(HostName);
        }
        return matcher.matches();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (ip.validateHost("http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/09/17/stax.html#id=abc")) {
            System.out.println("its valide host");
            else {
                System.out.println("its not valide URL/IP address");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use one of the existing url regex matchers. There are tons of them.

Comment: "Its fail." - you might want to specify that. In what way does it fail? Does `validateHost()` return `false`? Btw, providing `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` wouldn't require you to use character classes like `[A-Za-z...]`, i.e. just `[a-z...]` would make your expression shorter and much more readable (and you could add `(?i)` at the front of your expression to make it clear it is meant to be case-insensitive). That being said, for url validation you should use an already existing regex like Murat suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. Fail means its not matching the regular expression so it gives me  it is not valid URL( the one that i posted in my question specifically).

Comment: i tried most of the regular expressions that existing online but most of them are not matching like 30% of URLs specially the URL that i posted here all of online Regex are not matching it. the problem that i am facing with this URL(http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/09/17/stax.html#id=_hbc)  is  the (=) equal sign. If you removed the (=) that exiting in the anchor. the URL will match the regex. So i tried harder to escape the equal but i did not succeed i dont know why? i used ( \=) but no use its still not matching

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do this:

```
   public boolean validateHost(String host){
       matcher = patternHost.matcher(host);
       if (matcher.matches()) {
           String HostName = matcher.group(0);
           System.out.println(HostName);
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. i may little bit not clear in my question that because its my second time post here in the stack overview. My problem is not in the ValidateHost method. my problem is with this specific URL my regex pattern is not matching it. i tried hard with every possibility but i still not matching it . when i parsed i found that my problem is with equal sign that existing in the anchor part even though i tried harder to escape it but i failed

Comment: @MaxPody I've tested your code as it; it prints "its valide host".